# Is there a way to register a doubletab on a TabPanel?

Tags: sencha-touch, tabpanel

Is there a way to register a doubletab on a TabPanel?

Comment: Tap and doubletap is like registering click and double click with a mouse. In the following thread there is some nice code posted which you can use to attach both tap and doubletap to the same element (for instance a tabpanel): http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?105239-Tap-doubletap-amp-taphold-on-one-component&s=3b45a53c1c86e919bf3decf369d8f089&p=493539&viewfull=1#post493539

Comment: hey, thanx! but where to puit the listeners? dirctly inside the items of the TabPanel? tried that - not working...